# How to use Spring to inject an object in a setter that doesnt follow the Java bean specification?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I am trying to use [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) and [wx-xmlrpc](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/) together. The problem is that [XmlRpcClient](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/client/XmlRpcClient.html) has a [setConfig()](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/client/XmlRpcClient.html#setConfig(org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfig)) method that doesnt follow the Java Bean spec : the setter and the getter dont use the same Class. So Spring complaints when I have the following context.xml :

```
<bean id="xmlRpcClient" class="org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient">
    <property name="config">
        <bean class="org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl">
            <property name="serverURL" value="http://example.net" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It says : Bean property 'config' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Is there a way to override that ? I know I could write a specific factory for this bean, but it seems to me that it is not the last time I find this kind of problem. I work a lot with legacy code of dubious quality ... Being able to use Spring XML configuration with it would be a great help !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write a FactoryBean for that class and have it call the correct setter.

Comment: Not really the answer I'd like to have, but as it seems I cant do what I want in XML, a FactoryBean is the cleanest workaround.

Comment: FactoryBeans are there to allow you to integrate non-beans-compliant stuff into Spring. That's not a workaround, that's the intended solution.

Comment: All your bean entries in XML are in the end used to create a concrete BeanFactory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to override this using the Spring XML configuration.

An alternative to using a factory could be to make a subclass of XmlRpcClient that has a matching getter and setter for XmlRpcClientConfig (e.g. setClientConfig/getClientConfig). setClientConfig would simply call super.setConfig.