# Using MethodInvokingFactoryBean to set up unconventional beans

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to set up [HostConfiguration](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HostConfiguration.html) bean. One of the property it has is called `proxyHost`. However, the apache HostConfiguration class does not follow the java beans convention. The [setter](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HostConfiguration.html#setProxyHost%28org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProxyHost%29) for the proxyHost accepts an argument of type [ProxyHost](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ProxyHost.html) whereas the [getter](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HostConfiguration.html#getProxyHost%28%29) returns a String.

I have the following snippet in my `applicationContext.xml`.

```
    <bean id="proxyHost" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProxyHost">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="myproxy.com" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="8087" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="hostConfiguration" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration">
         <property name="proxyHost" ref="proxyHost" />
    </bean>
```

When I try to load the applicationContext for the app I get the following error since `HostConfigurationClass` does not have a `getProxyHost` that returns a ProxyHost or a setter that takes a String:-

> org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyExcep tion: Invalid property 'proxyHost' of bean class [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration]: Bean property 'proxyHost' is not writable or has an invalid setter method: Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

While searching on the springsource forum I came across this [thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=21991) where it was recommended to use [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) to solve this.

I am not exactly sure how using `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` would help since I would need a return type of `ProxyHost` from the method `getProxyHost()` to fix this, right? And I am not also sure about how to use it in this context. I am not clear on the internals of `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`. Therefore, if someone could please give me an example in the above context how to use `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` that would be of immense help.

Also is this generally the accepted way to set up beans like `HostConfiguration` that do not follow convention in spring?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Spring to inject an object in a setter that doesnt follow the Java bean specification ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215048/how-to-use-spring-to-inject-an-object-in-a-setter-that-doesnt-follow-the-java-bea)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First , instantiate  the `ProxyHost`
(i.e. `ProxyHost proxyHost = new ProxyHost("myproxy1.com",8080);`

```
<bean id="proxyHost" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProxyHost">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="myproxy1.com" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="8088" />
</bean>
```

Then instantiate  the `HostConfiguration` object
(i.e. `HostConfiguration hostConfiguration = new HostConfiguration();`

```
<bean id="hostConfiguration" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration" />
```

After that , use the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` to call `setProxyHost()` on the `HostConfiguration` and pass the `proxyHost` as argument.
(i.e. `hostConfiguration.setProxyHost(proxyHost);`)

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject">
                <ref local="hostConfiguration"/>
            </property>
            <property name="targetMethod">
                <value>setProxyHost</value>
            </property>
            <property name="arguments">
                <ref local="proxyHost"/>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer you can implement a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). If you are using spring 3.0 you could also take a look at the [Java Configuration](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/11/28/a-java-configuration-option-for-spring/) - @Configuration / @Bean.